# Splash page (not my idea) using jQuery to fadeIn/Out before going to first real page of site

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I am in the final throes of building a site, and the client wants a splash page. Mine is not to question why, mine is to get paid and fly...

So, here's the sequence of events I'm looking for:

Splash page opens. Logo fades in. Use clicks to enter. Logo fades out. First 'real' page of site opens.

I've got the first three events to work, and the fourth. It's getting the logo to fade out before opening the first real page.

Here's what I've got:

```
<div class="logo_container link" data="commercials.php">
<img src="images/logo_intro.jpg" alt="intro" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    $('.logo_container').hide();

    $('.logo_container').fadeIn(1000);

   $(".link").click(function(e) {
        $('.logo_container').fadeOut(1000);
        window.location = $(this).attr("data");
    });
});

</script>

</div>
```

But I'm not getting the fadeOut. It's just jumping to the attribute called in window.location, which is commercials.php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to use `window.location` in your callback method like so:

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
        $('.logo_container').fadeOut(1000, function(){
           window.location = $(this).attr("data");
        }); 
});
```

otherwise `window.location` will be called at the same time as the fade out event

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a callback to see when the fadeOut has completed.

Example from the documentation:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Replace animation complete line with `window.location = $(this).attr("data");`

Answer (score 0):

The `window.location` gets updated immediately after the fadeOut is started, so you never get chance to see it. Delay the change of `.location` by a method suitable for your framework (e.g. in MooTools it would be chain - I don't know jquery), or just schedule it to happend 1000ms in the future using the standard `setTimeout()`.